# Помогите с State на Aiogram python

Tags: telegram, бот, aiogram, state

Знаю что есть альтернатива register_next_step_handler на Aiogram, как мне сделать так, чтобы при любом сообщении, которое отправит пользователь в бота, ему бот присылал текст "хорошо, учту это"
Гуглил кучу статей но там идёт state через запись в Бд или хранилища но мне это не надо.
python

Answer (score 3):

Для этого дела тебе нужна машина состояний (FSM).
вот тут  можно узнать подробнее https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/fsm/

Так-же можно на ютубе глянкть по запросу fsm,  там есть одекватное видео.